# Find nearest multi-dimensional Array value from world coordinates, when the grid is not placed at world position 0,0

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a tile map. I'm looking to find the tiles array value from the players world mouse coordinates.

To help explain: normally the tile maps bottom left world position would be 0,0. 
World coordinates x14.2/y4.3 would correspond to 2DArray[14,4].

However, the bottom left of my grid could be anywhere, for example -14, -10. I need to somehow work out the offset to get the equivalent 2D array value.

I've included an image, which hopefully explains

[image: helpful image]

Comment: Actually the question is not clear for me. Dont you know the position of the points of your grid in world space ? And also why do you need another grid ? Does your grid move and re-create with user inputs ?

Comment: 1.) I know that the mouse is at 12,10. But I do not know how to make that relate to the the equivalent array value. 2.) No, but for sake of argument yes.

Comment: I mean how the gird created at first. We need to know at least a point postion of the grid and the distance between the points.

Answer (score 0):

A friend helped me with the answer. In pseudo-code its

gridX = Mathf.Round( (worldposition.x - gridposition.x ) / GridCellSizeX )

And here is what I used in c#

```
    float gridcellYSize = height / ((float)rows-1);
    float gridcellXSize = width / ((float)columns-1) ;
    float gridX = Mathf.Abs (Mathf.Round ((worldPos.x - AspectUtility.screenWorldRect.xMin ) / gridcellXSize) );
    float gridY = Mathf.Abs (Mathf.Round ((worldPos.y - AspectUtility.screenWorldRect.yMax ) / gridcellYSize) );
```